# PIXI.js : Code architecture to not recreate full scene at each frame

Tags: angular, ngrx, pixi.js

I am currently creating a web drawing software that uses PIXI.js and NgRx with Angular https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tz17.png.

For the moment the basic principle is as follows: the component managing the drawing area (a canvas) subscribes to state slices, and each time the state is updated, I call a method allowing to clean all the elements of the canvas, then add them back to the scene.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas-renderer',
  templateUrl: './canvas-renderer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas-renderer.component.scss']
})
export class CanvasRendererComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  frames$ = this.store$.select(framesSelector);
  app!: PIXI.Application;

  @ViewChild('canvasElement')
  canvasElement!: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
  constructor(
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private store$: Store<State>) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // this.onResize();
    const boundingClientRect = this.canvasElement.nativeElement.parentElement;
    if (boundingClientRect) {
      this.canvasElement.nativeElement.style.width = boundingClientRect.clientWidth + 'px';
      this.canvasElement.nativeElement.style.height = boundingClientRect.clientHeight + 'px';
    }
    this.app = new PIXI.Application({
      view: this.canvasElement.nativeElement,
      resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
      width: boundingClientRect?.clientWidth,
      height: boundingClientRect?.clientHeight,
      backgroundColor: 0xF0F4FA
    });

    this.frames$.subscribe(this.update.bind(this))


  }

  private update(frames :FrameState[]) {
    this.app.stage.removeChildren();
    const globalContainer = this.getGlobalContainer();
    this.app.stage.addChild(globalContainer);
    const screensContainer = new PIXI.Container();
    for (let i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
      const renderedFrame = this.getRenderedFrame(frames[i], frames, screensContainer);
      screensContainer.addChild(renderedFrame);
      for (let j = 0; j < frames[i].nodes.length; j++) {
        renderedFrame.addChild(this.getRenderedNode(frames[i].nodes[j], frames[i], frames));
      }
    }
    this.app.stage.addChild(screensContainer);
  }
}
```

I had several questions about this method:

- Currently all of the DisplayObject creation code is included in my canvas component. I wondered if there was a cleaner architecture to separate the drawn objects.
- How is it possible to have an architecture allowing to modify the generated DisplayObjects instead of destroying them and regenerating them?

**Edit 1**

Here is the code for `this.getRenderedNode()` method:

```
private getRenderedNode(node: NodeState, frame: FrameState | null, frames: FrameState[], matrix: PIXI.Matrix,
                        components: ComponentState[], offsetX: number = 0, offsetY: number = 0, interactive = true) {
  let rect = new PIXI.Container();
  if (node.type === 'line') {
    rect = this.getRenderedLine(node.x + (frame?.x || 0) + offsetX, node.y + (frame?.y || 0) + offsetY,
      node.x + (frame?.x || 0) + offsetX + node.width,
      node.y + (frame?.y || 0) + offsetY + node.height,
      PIXI.utils.string2hex(node.foreground), 1);
  } else if (node.type === 'rect') {
    rect = this.getRenderedRect(node.x + (frame?.x || 0) + offsetX, node.y + (frame?.y || 0) + offsetY, node.width, node.height,
      PIXI.utils.string2hex(node.background), undefined, 1);
  } else if (node.type === 'image') {
    rect = this.getRenderedImage(node.x + (frame?.x || 0) + offsetX, node.y + (frame?.y || 0) + offsetY, node.width, node.height,
      node.imageSource || '');
  } else if (node.type === 'text') {
    rect = this.getRenderedText(node.x + (frame?.x || 0) + offsetX, node.y + (frame?.y || 0) + offsetY, node.text || '',
      PIXI.utils.string2hex(node.foreground), node.fontSize || 0, matrix);
  } else if (node.type === 'ellipse') {
    rect = this.getRenderedEllipse(node.x + (frame?.x || 0) + offsetX, node.y + (frame?.y || 0) + offsetY, node.width, node.height,
      PIXI.utils.string2hex(node.background), undefined, 1);
  } else if (node.type === 'component') {
    rect = this.getRenderedComponent(frame, node, frames, matrix, components);
  } else if (node.type === 'list') {
    rect = this.getRenderedList(node, frame, frames, matrix, components);
  }
  if (!node.children?.some(x => x.isSelected) && (!findParentNode(frames, node) || node.isSelected)) {
    rect.interactive = interactive;
    rect
      .on('pointerdown', e => this.onElementMouseDown(node.id, e))
      .on('pointerup', e => this.onElementMouseUp(node.id, e))
      .on('pointerupoutside', e => this.onElementMouseUp(node.id, e))
      .on('pointerover', e => this.onElementMouseOver(node.id, e))
      .on('pointerout', e => this.onElementMouseOut(node.id, e))
      .on('pointermove', e => this.onElementMouseMove(node.id, e))
      .on('dblclick', e => this.onElementMouseDoubleClick(node.id, e));
  }

  return rect;
}
```

Comment: can you also show `getRenderedNode` method?

Comment: The `getRenderedNode` method basically returns a Container which can contain either text, a rectangle, or some other type of basic element. The question has been edited to include this portion of code as well.